# Proper Usage of TcpListener in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I am experimenting with client-server applications using the System.Net namespace in C#.  I am currently using the following TcpListener code to listen for incoming connections:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 62126);
List<Connection> ClientConnections = new List<Connection>();
while (true)
{
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        if (listener.Pending())
        {
            ClientConnections.Add(new Connection(listener.AcceptTcpClient()));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(Where Connection is a class that takes the accepted TcpClient via `public Connection(TcpClient client) { ... }`  and maintains the connection on a separate thread.)

Do I need to invoke `listener.Start()` every time an incoming connection is accepted or is that unnecessary?

Comment: Take a look at using [BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It is a good idea to avoid while(true) loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're busy waiting if no pending connection requests exist. This is not necessary. Just delete that `if`. Make sure you understand why it is not necessary.

I do not understand why there are two nested loops. You only need one. Call `Start` only once.

I can tell that you have not read the documentation. Quite dangerous. You are capable of answering these questions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No. Start needs to be called only once. Remove the outer while loop